# Find items in an array that have changed

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS I'm loading an array of items from an AJAX request and when I save them again, I'd like to send back only the items that have changed rather than the whole thing. But I don't see a simple way to get just the items that have changed. On load, I tried doing this:

```
originalData = angular.copy(data);
$scope.notifications = data;
```

So then when I save I can do this:

```
var changed = $scope.notifications.filter(function (item, idx) {
    return !angular.equals(item, originalData[idx]);         // hopefully they stay 
                                                             // in the same order!?!
});
```

Which seems to work, but doesn't feel terribly robust. Note the comment about order. I don't currently reorder the items, but I would like to allow sorting eventually and I fear that will completely trash this and force me to try and look up the item in the `originalData` array by `id` (which is the one unique property each item has), but that would be `O(n^2)`. Am I missing something obvious here? I know angular tracks if items are dirty and applies classes to bound DOM elements. I also know you can use `$watch`, but I think I'd need to set up a watch for *every* property on *every* item and set some kind of `isDirty` flag on each item so I can filter in save.

Comment: You could use $watchCollection but that would only notify you of the change.  Also you may want to use the $hash instead of the index.  We will need to accomplish this soon as well; I will make a plunker.

Comment: @CorySilva: As I understand it `$watchCollection` will only inform you if an item is added, removed or moved within a collection. I'm looking for has an item's (in the collection) properties changed.

Comment: Yeah you are right, it would be $watch(func..., true)  [see this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LuQANsnUiaR3XT2Ltb0W?p=preview).  Also i misspoke about $hash, it is $$hashKey.  my bad.

Comment: @CorySilva: On `$hashKey`, as I understand it, that won't be added until it's bound in an `ng-repeat`, so my copy of the original data doesn't have it. So I'm not sure I can use it. Using `$watch` on the array will notify you when something has changed, but it won't tell you which item changed (`newValue` is the whole array).

Comment: Maybe underscore's _.difference will here but in our app we would be doing this difference check in the service before committing changes to the server.  It might be worth while looking at [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseArray.js#L350) to see how they accomplish their array updates if you need it more real time.

Comment: When you make changes to an item, what happens? how are items changed? via user input? because you can mark items in the array as changed with a flag. Then loop through the array to check for a changed flag and send only those back.

Comment: @EliteOctagon: Yes, I know. That's why I said I could add `$watch`es to every item for every property, but that seems horrible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do this, which I think is better than the original solution in that it keeps a copy of the original with each item. When I load the data, I do this:

```
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
    item.$original = angular.copy(item);
}
```

This will make a deep copy of the item and store it in `$original`. Note that the `$` prefix to the property name is important because when I go to save, I do this:

```
var changed = $scope.notifications.filter(function (item, idx) {
    return !item.$original || !angular.equals(item, item.$original);
});
```

`angular.equals` will ignore any properties that start with `$` (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)):

> During a property comparison, properties of function type and properties with names that begin with $ are ignored.

So it will do a deep compare of the `item` with `item.$original` without trying to compare the `$original` property itself. The first clause of the `or` takes care of the case of a new item (which obviously won't have an `$original` property).

Now it won't matter if I reorder the array later because instead of keeping a copy of the whole array, I'm only keeping a copy of each item with the item itself.